# How to pass path params to child component of Route in React?

Tags: reactjs

```
              <Route exact path="/(register|login)">
                <Register initial_tab="(register|login)"/>
              </Route>
```

Essentially, the above is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: you can use, useLocation to get pathname

Comment: you should wrap your component with the `withRouter` HOC. this will expose the router props to your component